# moment.js does not take user input

Tags: javascript, parsing, momentjs

Moment.js returns **NaN** when I attempt to subtract time from given race start date to time of finishing the race. My code is below. I am looking to get the results in minutes. For instances if the user inputs "01-02-2021 08:00 AM " It should return 1440 minutes. Any suggestions ?

```
let startTime = moment('01-01-2021 08:00 AM');
let endingTime = moment(document.getElementById('arrival').value);
let minuteCount = endingTime.diff(startTime, 'minutes'); 




document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = minuteCount;
});

console.log(minuteCount);
```

Comment: These are not recognized RFC2822 or ISO format dates. No-one should be using dates in the format MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY in programming.

Comment: Look at [moment.stringFormat](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). If you're getting your date time from html's datetime-local input type, moment should be able to parse that natively.

Comment: @CharlesBamford Yes tried that and still getting NaN, I think I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem of logic, the result it's `NaN` because you when you execute the code achive the difference between `startTime` and `endTime` but this last one is an empty string and moment can't convert this string into a moment object. Also your code calculate the `minuteCount` just one time, when it starts.

You can move the first three rows inside the event function, so when you click the button your code calculate every time the minute diference.

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (document.getElementById('arrival').value) {
    let startTime = moment('01-01-2021 08:00 AM');
    let endingTime = moment(document.getElementById('arrival').value);
    let minuteCount = endingTime.diff(startTime, 'minutes');

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = minuteCount;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'No date selected';
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<button id="myBtn">Click me</button>

<input type="datetime-local" id="arrival" value="() => moment().toDate()">

<div id="result"></div>
```